# Undefined reference to a private function of the class

Tags: c++, class, sdl, undefined

So I'm debugging some horrible code I slung together and finally widdled my way down to (hopefully) the last error in my scene_manager.cpp but I don't seem to understand why I'm getting it. 
Error

```
|22|undefined reference to `scene_manager::applySurface(int, int, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*)'|
```

**scene_manager.cpp**

```
#include "scene_manager.h"

scene_manager::scene_manager(screen_manager* s){
    screen = s;
}

void scene_manager::add_object(object_manager* obj){
    if(game_objects.find(obj->get_name()) != game_objects.end()){
        game_objects[obj->get_name()] = obj;
    }
}

void applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination){
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, destination, &offset);
}

int scene_manager::render(){
    for(iter = game_objects.begin(); iter != game_objects.end();iter++){
        applySurface(game_objects.at(iter->first)->get_x(),game_objects.at(iter->first)->get_y(),game_objects.at(iter->first)->get_sprite(),screen->get_screen());
    }
    if(SDL_Flip(screen->get_screen()) == -1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**scene_manager.h**

```
#ifndef SCENE_MANAGER_H
#define SCENE_MANAGER_H
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "object_manager.h"
#include "screen_manager.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

class scene_manager{
public:
    scene_manager();
    scene_manager(screen_manager* s);
    void add_object(object_manager* obj);
    int render();
private:
    std::map<std::string,object_manager*>game_objects;
    std::map<std::string,object_manager*>::iterator iter;
    screen_manager* screen;
    void applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination);
};
#endif
```

Comment: oh, jeebus... `for(iter` he's storing iterators in member variables. ABANDON PLANET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, this line

```
void applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination){
```

wants to read

```
void scene_manager::applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination){
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `scope resolution operator` when you define the `applySurface`function outside the class.

```
void scene_manager::applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination){
     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: what is actually inside the class? if you have added the scope resolution operator when you define the member function, could you update your post? It is not clear what the issue is then.